# Concatenate values which don't exist in the column

Tags: sql-server

Here is the table:

```
Inspector---------DocID

T01-----------3
T01-----------5
T01-----------6
T01-----------2
T02-----------4
T02-----------3
T03-----------3
T03-----------5
```

I like to find inspectors who don't own documents (3,5,6) and then concatenate the docIDs which don't exist in the column.

Result:

```
InspectorID-----DocID
T02--------------5,6
T03--------------6
```

Stuff and For XML function can be used to concatenate values but how I find non existing values and then concatenate them in one query.

Comment: what is the question? sql statement?

Comment: yes sql statements to achieve above mentioned reults

Comment: T02 own doc 3, and T03 own doc 5, you example/your requirements are not well defined..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT B.Inspector, A.DocId 
FROM (SELECT DocId FROM YourTable) A, (SELECT Inspector FROM YourTable) B 
WHERE A.DocID IN(3,5,6) 
EXCEPT 
SELECT Inspector, DocId 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE DocID IN(3,5,6)
);

SELECT ReportId, Docs = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + DocId
           FROM cte B 
           WHERE A.Inspector= B.Inspector
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM cte A
GROUP BY Inspector
```

Comment: how would you do it in one sql statement?

Comment: These are two solutions choose one... what else do you need?

Comment: sql statement to achieve the results as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem, this is an end to end solution..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41226/discussion-between-user1263981-and-yosi)